# How to initialize CoreWCF.OperationContext in unit tests?

Tags: .net, http, wcf, http-status-codes, corewcf

I have a **CoreWCF .NET 6** service that returns custom HTTP status codes with this code:

`var requestProp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty(); OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = requestProp; requestProp.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;`

The problem is I cannot initialize or mock the **OperationContext.Current** in my unit tests.

It is possible to do it in old **WCF .NET Framework 4.8** by doing:

`var factory = new ChannelFactory<IManagementService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/Program.Interface/ManagementService.svc")); OperationContext.Current = new OperationContext(factory.CreateChannel() as IContextChannel);`

This is no longer possible because **ChannelFactory **is from the **System.ServiceModel** package whereas my IManagementService service contract is using **CoreWCF **package.

I also tried to use the **HttpContextAccessor**, it is easy to use it in unit tests *but the HTTP status code doesn't change in my service* !!

Does anyone have an idea on how to initialize the **CoreWCF.OperationContext** in unit tests ??

Comment: See if the initialization context of [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/durable-instance-context) is helpful to you.

Comment: @dotnetammar - I am also facing similar issue. If you found the solution, please post your answer in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the IManagementService to use the attributes defined in the System.ServiceModel.Primitives package instead of the ones in CoreWCF. CoreWCF will theoretically continue to use those as well, while it becomes possible to invoke the ChannelFactory on them too.